# Performance Analysis of Sharepoint Web app

Tags: 2010, web-application, performance, 2016

Currently, we have 2 different SharePoint 2010 webapps for

1. Mysite(Personal User Data )
2. Collaboration Room / Sharepoint Workspace

We are planning to migrate to SharePoint 2016 . We are considering to make a single webapp and below that we will make 2 site collections each for Mysite(Personal User Data )  and Collaboration Room / Sharepoint Workspace .

Can anyone tell me is there any performance issue if we do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no performance issue, in fact there is an argument that this actually has less impact as you are only using one app pool instead of two.

I do this regularly with host named site collections and have had no issue.

Saying all that before you do this make sure that there are no solutions or other scenarios that will have a detrimental impact on the other. Also be aware of any SLAs you may have. Is it more important for you to guarantee a higher level of up time for your collab sites etc.

Keep an eye on your performance and make sure to baseline but this really applies to SharePoint in general...

Answer (score 1):

What do you intend to do is called **HNSC** (Host name Site collection) that mean avoid creating multiple web application with multiple application pool,

This is very useful for performance , So **there's no issue for performance with this method**. for more details check [The Expense of Application Pools](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/08/expense-application-pools/)

But I think the main issue will be related to `capacity planning` , where the two site collection will be created in the same content database, so you should limit the number of site collection at the content database

Then create a new one that you hold the second site collection. To lock down a content database check [Content Database Consideration](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/28/lock-down-the-project-web-app-content-database/)

[image]

In my humble opinion , In your situation , you have My Site host , so I suggest creating two web applications with the same application pool

- One for the Collaboration Room web application.
- Second for `My site`.

In this case, you cared about performance, capacity  consideration .